# Delete last value of a list and returns the deleted value?

Tags: java

How can I write a method that deletes the last value of a list and returns the deleted value? If the list is empty, it should throw an exception. This is for a linkedlist class.

Thanks!

edit: nevermind! i'm allowed to use the java built in method. thanks!

Comment: Tag it as homework, if required.

Comment: I assume you are writing the class yourself? Otherwise there is a method for doign exactly what you want. linkedlist.removeLast();

Comment: Is it `java.util.LinkedList` or your own custom implementation?

Comment: Unfortunately *we* don't get credit for doing your homework for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

java.util.LinkedList has the removeLast() method out of the box...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [removeLast()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeLast%28%29) method from [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). If your variable is of type [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) then this method will not be available, you may have to cast it back to LinkedList again/change the type to LinkedList

Answer (score 1):

Is this homework?  LinkedList in Java has a removeLast method with returns the element removed.

Answer (score 1):

I hear a distant [pop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#pop%28%29) coming from a [Stack](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) ;)

Unfortunatly, [`Stack`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Stack.java) is a subclass of `Vector` and not of `LinkedList` (Hint hidden behind the last link ;) )

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList has a method called `remove`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove%28int%29

It will return the element removed.